# "Nested" RecyclerViews

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

*Hi everyone.*

I've come up with an idea for an Android App, and I was thinking how to turn my thoughts into something working. I know how to program for Android even though I'm not that advanced as you might see, so I wanted some tips from you guys who I'm sure will be able to help.

---

### Idea

I was thinking about an App to organize stuff, see your objects on a `list` and be able to *add*, *move* or *remove* them from the `list`.

---

### Thoughts

I first thought I needed a `RecyclerView`to display each item. Then I thought every item itself might be a **box**, and so be containing other items inside: this brought me to think of a sort of ***"nested" system*** of `RecyclerView`s. Before going too deep into this system I had to clarify each item should have been a `Class`, each of which should have had a `RecyclerView` assigned.

---

### Question

I was wondering how I could make this "***nested" system*** of `RecyclerView`s. I thought about making a `RecyclerView` an `object`, because I need each `RecyclerView` to *display*, *function* and *be* always the same in any screen of any item. But I don't know what the best way is.

Should I make it an `object`? How do I create a new `RecyclerView` through a button so the user can *first* **tap** an item and then, eventually, **tap** a button (inside the item details view for instance) to make it a **box** item and so *create* and *open* a `RecyclerView` **when tapped**?

---

### P.S.

It may seem like multiple questions but it actually is only **one**: how to *add* and *display* a `RecycerView` when I **tap** a **button** inside a details screen of an item, of course automatically (have a reference to that `RecyclerView`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `RecyclerView` that holds your items list, let's call it `rv_list`, this `RecyclerView` has an adapter that takes each item and adapts it to an xml layout `row_item.xml` that you should define. Now to make an item itself display its own recyclerview you should put a recyclerview inside `row_item.xml` and populate it when adapting that item to `rv_list` inside the method `onBindViewHolder`.